# How to record video when application is in background ios

Tags: ios, video, background, gpuimage

How can i record / capture video from application and once start recording, when i press home button and application goes to background, recording video should be continued even if application is in background.

How can GPUImage framework help in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Applications running in the background don't have access to the camera. Also, GPUImage requires access to OpenGL ES, which is also something that background applications are not allowed to use.